# System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit from System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder instance

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, codedom

I'm looking at CodePlex code for TLBImp2 and want to generate C# source code from the IL emitted.

Is there a way to get a System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit from a System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't. I thin kyou want to attack the problem at an earlier stage, before the IL is generated.